# Compile python3 script with Cython | CentOs 6.x

Tags: python-3.x, centos, cython

I've previously compiled the script with cython on ubuntu and it works fine on all ubuntu os but it doesnt works on centos, it failes with this error: `error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

So I tried to compile the script on centos but when I try to compile the C source code generated by Cython with the following command `gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.6m -o a.o script.c -lpython3.6m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl` 
I get this error `script.c:4:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
script.c:6:6: error: #error Python headers needed to compile C extensions, please install development version of Python.`.

I've tried to install python3 dev libs but seems like they don't exist for CentOs 6, and search for someone who has the same problem but I haven't found anything usefull so far.
I think I can solve the issuse by installing python3-devel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7

for centos 6 install ius repo like this:
yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el6.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm -y (source: https://ius.io/setup)